# SwiftUI NavigationLink navigationBarHidden with sheet flashes screen

Tags: swiftui, ios13, navigationbar

Sorry for the bad quality. The content shows how the screen is refreshed when a new view is shown in SwiftUI.
The Welcome screen has the navigation bar hidden:

```
var body: some View { 
        SwiftUI.Form {
         NavigationLink(destination: FlashingView { self.done = true }) {
                    Text(UI.doSomething)
         }
         ...  
        }

}
.navigationBarTitle("")
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

and the FlashingView:

```
var body: some View {
        SwiftUI.Form {
        .....
   }
}
.navigationBarTitle("My Title Showing", displayMode: .inline)
```

Any idea how to work around this?

[image]

Sample project on Dropbbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/00yq1qns7ywds0a/NavigationTest.zip?dl=0

Update: it turns out the cause of the issue is the `sheet` modifier. Search for `// Comment/uncomment to test` in the code to test.

Comment: Would you prepare minimal reproducible example? which Xcode? Device/Simulator/Preview?

Comment: @Asperi thanks for the suggestion. I created a sample project, find the link in the description. It turns out the `sheet` modifier causing it somehow. I tested it on Xcode 11.7 running on the simulator iPhone SE (and others iOS 13.7)

Comment: On iOS 14 with Xcode Version 12.0 (12A7209) seems to work correctly.